# .NET Wrapper to C++ code: CS0122 is inaccessible due to its protection level error

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, wrapper

I´m trying to build a C++/CLR wrapper to call my C++ code from inside a C# .Net application.

Here are the steps followed:

**C++ Project:**

***cppproject.h***

```
#ifndef _CPPPROJECT_H
#define _CPPPROJECT_H


typedef enum {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR
} StatusEnum;

namespace cppproject
{
    class MyClass {

    public:
        MyClass();
        virtual ~MyClass();
        StatusEnum Test(); 

    };
}

#endif
```

***cppproject.cpp***

```
#include "cppproject.h"

namespace cppproject {

    MyClass::MyClass() {};
    MyClass::~MyClass() {};

    StatusEnum MyClass::Test() 
    { 
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Now the wrapper project (C++/CLR type) to tie together C# and C++:

***wrapper.h***

```
// wrapper.h

#pragma once

#include "cppproject.h"

using namespace System;

namespace wrapper {

    public ref class Wrapper
    {
        public:
            /*
             * The wrapper class
             */
            cppproject::MyClass* wrapper;

            Wrapper();
            ~Wrapper();

            StatusEnum Test();
    };
}
```

***wrapper.cpp***

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "wrapper.h"

namespace wrapper {

    Wrapper::Wrapper()
    {
        wrapper = new cppproject::MyClass();
    }

    Wrapper::~Wrapper()
    {
        delete wrapper;
    }

    StatusEnum Wrapper::Test() 
    { 
        return wrapper->Test(); 
    };
}
```

And finally the C# code, where I´m getting the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using wrapper;


namespace netproject
{
    /*
     * Enums
     */
    public enum StatusEnum {
        SUCCESS,
        ERROR
    };

    public partial class netproject
    {
        public const int MAX_REPORT_DATA_SIZE = 1024;
        public wrapper.Wrapper wrapper;

        public netproject() { wrapper = new wrapper.Wrapper(); }
        ~netproject() { wrapper = null; }

        public StatusEnum Test() 
        { 
            var sts = wrapper.Test(); <<- ERROR
            return (netproject.StatusEnum) sts;<<- ERROR 
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler error at the C# project:

```
error CS0122: 'wrapper.Wrapper.Test()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
error CS0426: The type name 'StatusEnum' does not exist in the type 'netproject.netproject'
```

I can´t understand that. `Test` is defined public in both the wrapper project and the C++ project. And the `StatusEnum` is also public in the C# project above the error line.

Help appreaciated to find out what´s going on here....

Comment: You cannot use an unmanaged enum type in a C# program.  You must declare a `public enum class` in your C++/CLI code.  Just cast from int to convert.

Comment: Re `netproject.netproject`: [Do not name a class the same as its namespace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/).

Comment: Thanks Hans, but can you please elaborate or point an example... I don´t have a enum in my wrapper.... The cast is done at the return time at `(netproject.StatusEnum)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef enum {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR
} StatusEnum;
```

This is not something that is accessible in C#. As I see it, you have two options:

1) You can make the enum a managed enum.

```
public enum class StatusEnum {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR
};
```

2) I'm generally not a fan of enums that only have two values. In many cases, a Boolean will work just as well.

```
public ref class Wrapper
{
    // returns true on success.
    bool Test();
};
```

Comment: Thanks David. This code is an example code to isolate the bug - I reduced it to a minial set of projects with same behaviour. My real application has several enums with dozens of options....Question: The `public enum class StatusEnum` will go in the C++/CLI code ? Will my C# see this enums (they will be in a different namespace: `wrapper`)